# Is there a way to highlight specific words in search results?

Tags: google-sheets, search, highlight

Is there a way to highlight particular words in cells that I enter into the search window? Sometimes, working with a huge text we need to find only several words among long text and we have to read through all cell content to find it manually because the search option only highlights an entire cell where a searched word is located.

Is there a method to make Google Sheets highlight not an entire cell but specific words in search results or is it technically impossible?

Comment: Welcome to Webapps. Please read [ask] and [About asking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Also, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if an answer addressed your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote))

Answer (score 1):

> **Google Sheets do NOT highlight specific words in text.
>
>   Google sheets ONLY show the cells where your search terms are included**

After finding the right sheet, **use your browser's search feature**.

Please **pay attention on the counted results**.
Google Sheets function ONLY shows found cells (including the search terms)

#### This is what you see in **Google Chrome**:

[image: Chrome search]

#### ...and this when **using Firefox**:

[image]

Comment: Google Sheets has it's own find tool.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for the comment. Still -as pointed out- _"...the search option highlights an entire cell where a searched word is located"_.  **can it pinpoint and highlight the exact word within the contents of a cell**? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry for my unclear comment. Google Sheets has it's own find tool, that could overtaken the Ctrl+F keyboard shortcut depending on where is the focus set, by the other hand the not all web browsers will highlight all the searched word instances. Do you tried to use the web browser search feature? What browser do you used?

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for commenting. You are correct about _"...depending on where is the focus set"_. That is why I mentioned _"...use your browser's search feature"_. Please use my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

- press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`F`</kbd>**
- type your word to find the cell
- select the cell
- click into address bar
- press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`F`</kbd>**
- type the word to find the possition

[image: 0]